# How to testing Spring Boot REST with Spock/Geb after server has been started?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spock, geb

I would like to test a REST service from Spock or GEB but would like to fireup the server before the tests are started. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Spock has support for `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` yet. Please raise an issue with them. You can probably use the existing support for `@ContextConfiguration` though, as long as you manually add the right initializers (see [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-configfileapplicationcontextinitializer-test-utility)).